# GMSPlace - coordinate property missing - iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, gmsplace

In my iOS app, I have the Google Maps SDK and I am using a [GMSPlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_place_picker?hl=en) to pick a place around specific coordinates like this:

```
//center is a CLLocationCoordinate2D

CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001,center.longitude + 0.001);
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001,center.longitude - 0.001);
GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast coordinate:southWest];

GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
   _placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];


       [_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {

                    if (error != nil) {
                      NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                    else if (place) {

                        CLLocationCoordinate2D c = place.coordinate;
                       //place.coordinate doesn't exist

                    }   

        }];
```

however there is no place.coordinate property despite Google stating there is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_place.html#a3dc43865df0de69b6b1203a15a745efc)
Any ideas why this is missing ?

Comment: did you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in Swift, but this might be helpful.  The 'coordinates' property of GMSPlace comes up as an optional, so it may not be required to have a value.  Can you check its existence?

As a workaround, I'm looking up the coordinate using a '[lookupPlaceID](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details)' call based on the 'googlePlaceID', but it costs an additional API call.